# AWS-SDK in Meteor (Angular2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor

I've installed aws-sdk into Meteor + Angular2 app as below:

```
meteor npm install aws-sdk --save
```

I'm trying to using AWS as below:

```
import AWS from  'aws-sdk';
```

but it says "Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'."
I'm trying to follow the instructions from this link: http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/3rd-party-libraries

I might be doing something silly, but still could not figure it out.
Thanks for your time.

Update:
Tried this: https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html

Module '"node_modules/moment/moment"' has no default export.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://atmospherejs.com/peerlibrary/aws-sdk

```
Adding this package to your Meteor application adds AWS object into the global scope, which you can then use according to the documentation.
```

So using AWS global variable.

That works even though the meteor consoles gives some warnings.